# how to programmatically load data into a table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to load some data for the last 2 years and the data is pretty much static and this is what I mean:

```
Date         UserName    Hours
1/1/2014     Mike01      10
1/2/2014     Mike01      10
1/3/2014     Mike01      10
1/4/2014     Mike01      10
.
.
7/30/2015     Mike01     10
```

so UserName and Hours are always the same and i would also like to exclude weekends.  I have spent so many hours but could not figure out so please help.  thanks

Comment: So the data is already in a table and you're trying to transfer it to another?

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: are you trting to insert data from a file into the database or inserting it from one table to the other?

Comment: What error are you getting?   Can you show some of the results of your efforts up to now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

Since the max recursion here can be 731 i have used `Recursive CTE` to generate dates. There are other options to generate dates like tally table.

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Cast(Cast(Year(getdate())-1 AS CHAR(4)) + '-01-01' AS DATE) AS dates 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, dates) 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  dates < dateadd(dd,-1,CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(dd, -( Day(Getdate()) - 1 ),Getdate())))
        ) 
SELECT dates, 
       username, 
       hours 
FROM   cte 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Mike01' AS username, 
                          10       AS hours) A 
Where datename(weekday,dates) not in ('saturday','sunday')
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffa43/19)

**Note :** In Demo i started the date from last month first day

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
IF OBJECT_ID('UsersTable') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE UsersTable ([Date] DATE, UserName VARCHAR(250), [Hours] TINYINT)
GO

DECLARE @Startdt DATETIME = '2013-07-31'
DECLARE @UsersTable TABLE ([Date] DATE, UserName VARCHAR(250), [Hours] TINYINT)

WHILE @Startdt <= GETDATE()
BEGIN
    IF DATENAME(weekday, @Startdt) NOT IN ('saturday','sunday')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @UsersTable
        SELECT @Startdt
            ,'Mike01'
            ,10
    END

    SET @Startdt = DATEADD(dd, 1, @Startdt)
END

INSERT INTO UsersTable
SELECT *
FROM @UsersTable vt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM UsersTable ut
        WHERE ut.[Date] = vt.[Date]
        )

SELECT *
FROM UsersTable

DROP TABLE UsersTable
```